# Heroku: Force Error Backtrace To Display In Development Mode

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I am running a sinatra application on Heroku, and I'm seeing the generic error page:

[image: Heroku Generic Error]

### Stuff I've Tried So Far

1. `heroku logs` returns a generic "H10 - Application Crashed" error, which doesn't tell me what the actual cause is.
2. I've used heroku config vars to set `RACK_ENV=development` and verified that it is set that way using `heroku config`.  I thought this would force a backtrace to be displayed on the screen but it does not.

### Questions

1. How can I force a backtrace to be displayed in dev mode?
2. What else can I do to track down the source of this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding the [`show_exceptions` setting](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Available%20Settings)? Also, do you get this error locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a response from Heroku support about this.

Everything I did was correct, the problem is the application boot errors won't display to the screen, and this was a boot error.  The source of the error was further back in the backtrace in `heroku logs`, so that was in fact the right place to look in this case, I just missed it.

Setting `RACK_ENV=development` is the correct way to display application runtime errors to the screen, according to support.